# How to optimize JAXB deserialization of list of objects?

Tags: jaxb, spring-webflux, spring-webclient

I want to deserialize RSS channel and I have the following class:

```kotlin
    @XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.NONE)
    data class Channel(
      @field:XmlElement
      val item: List<Item>
    )
```

I would like to stop deserializing this class after one element will appear in the `item` list since that list contains hundreds of items and I need only the first one.

Is there any annotation that I can put on `item` so JAXB will know that I need only one element?

Comment: If you try to change it to `String` then it would take the last element. So can you set the size of the `List` to 1 rest will be ignored during the `unmarshalling` process. One more approach is to delete all entries from the `List` except the first using the `afterUnmarshal`. Not sure if any of these suits you.

Comment: @BATMAN_2008 `Item` is a complex type (it has few fields etc.) so I don't know if I want to deserialize it to `String`. I want to have a memory-efficient solution that will stop unmarshalling after the first element.